# Changing ASP.NET MVC urls with RouteConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc

To keep the URLs organized, I wanted to customize it using the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` method, but I couldn't do it because I am a newbie.

All my code is messed up. I gave up but I have a question in my mind.

For example, when logging in, it says `/Login/Login` in the URL. Is it bad usage to see controller and action names here?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web site, the address is, to a degree (but read on), irrelevant. It's just an address. It might as well be [a GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (e.g. `/8b7b314b-ff6d-4ead-a9cb-db6c7e9ce781`).

Cases where the address turns out not to be irrelevant after all:

- One or more URL segments may disclose [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) or other sensitive information. This is *not* irrelevant, and should not happen.
- Users may bookmark URLs. Once you've published a URL, you ought to keep serving it forever. [Cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) (but in reality, many sites don't respect that rule).

A URL like `/Login/Login` looks unprofessional to me (mostly because of the repetition) but that said, most of the times, I probably wouldn't even notice.

Now, if, instead of a web site, this is a [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), URLs are often considered part of the API design, in which case an address like `/Login/Login` rarely is good design.